# php script command line execution issue

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments, taskscheduler

I have checked all the questions here and googled all available questions on this. However, nothing helped me debug this.

I have a php script log.php from which I try to run local functions like updating a database and writing to a file log.txt.  I am trying to run this with task windows task scheduler from a bat file log.bat placed in the system32 folder. However, this runs fine on the browser and updates the database and the log.txt file, but in the bat file / command line , it executes the php file but neither the database is updated nor the log.txt is updated.

log.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    error_reporting('E_All');
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','')  or die("CONNECT Error : ".$conn->error);

    $chkuser=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username')") or die("CHECK USER ERROR : ".$conn->error);

    if($chkuser){
        echo "<p>USER 'username'@'localhost' EXISTS";
    } else {
        $user=mysqli_query($conn,"CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';");
        ///  or die("CREATE USER Error : ".$conn->error);
        if($user) {
            echo "<p>USER 'username'@'localhost' with PASSWORD 'password' CREATED Successfully !</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>USER 'username'@'localhost' with  PASSWORD 'password' CREATION FAILED !!!</p>"; 
        }
    }

    $grant = mysqli_query($conn,"GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost'"); 
    //     or die("GRANT PRIVILEGES Error : ".$conn->error);

    if($grant) {
        echo "<p>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO 'avion'@'localhost' EXECUTED Successfully !</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO 'username'@'localhost'   FAILED !</p>";
    }

    $dbase=mysqli_query($conn," CREATE DATABASE login"); 
    // or die("Table DATABASE Error : ".$conn->error);

    if($dbase) { 
        echo "<p>DATABASE login CREATED Successfully !</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p> Database Create Error : ".$conn->error."</p>";
    }

    if(mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'login'")) {
        mysqli_select_db($conn,'login');
        $table=mysqli_query($conn, "CREATE TABLE login (Date DATETIME, id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(id))");
        // or die("Table Create Error : ".$conn->error);

        if($table) {
            echo "<p>TABLE login CREATED Successfully !</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p> Table Create Error :".$conn->error."</p>";
        }

        $addlog=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO login (Date) VALUES('$date')");

        if($addlog) {
            echo "<p>TABLE log UpDATED !</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p> Add Log Error :".$conn->error."</p>";
        }

        $msg=$date.PHP_EOL;

        if(is_file("log.txt")) {
            $fh=fopen("log.txt","a");
        } else {
            $fh=fopen("log.txt","w");
        }

        $fw=fwrite($fh, $msg);

        if($fw) {
            echo "<p>Log file Updated !</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p> Log file Not Updated !</p>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "<p>Table Not Created Bcoz DATABASE login DOES NOT EXIST !</p>";   
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

log.bat

```
"C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\php\php_runningversion\php.exe" -f "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\log\log.php"
```

Output in console window when log.bat is shows all success messages. But Database or log.txt is not updated.

What am I doing wrong here ?

PS : I have other two bat files that run well on task scheduler. One sends an email through Gmail and other sends SMS through a third party script.

Comment: Did you check current working directory?

Comment: Yes @RayRadin. The directories are fine. log.php and log.txt  is in the /path/log/ folder and batch file (log.bat) is in windows/system32/ folder. And I am running the log.bat  file on command line from inside the system32 folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to test your code and found something odd.
But first of all, this line:

```
error_reporting('E_All');
```

Is actually the same as this:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Yup, you are disabling error reporting.
It should be:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now, that odd thing is the `log.txt` file is actually created in `C:\Users\RRadin\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.
To remedy this, add `__DIR__` to the filename.
Like this:

```
if(is_file(__DIR__."/log.txt")) {
    $fh=fopen(__DIR__."/log.txt","a");
} else {
    $fh=fopen(__DIR__."/log.txt","w");
}
```

Unfortunately I can't reproduce your database update problem.
The `login` table in my database is updated just fine.
I executed the script 6 times and it has 6 records now.

Comment: You nailed it @Ray Radin. It was the _DIR_ that did it. As for the E_ALL, if I don't use the quotes, it throws an error "Use of Undefined Constanr E_ALL assumed 'E_ALL' " in cmd window. And the database is getting updated now. I don't know what i tried in between, it started working. Thanks a ton for the solution to the log.txt update.